# Tkinter probelm with Keybinds

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, bind

I wrote a simple GUI with tkinter and used the arrow keys to coordinate throug the buttons/ functions. But I have run into problem where i can use the arrows keys as much as I want to, but if I  hit Enter, it opens the website but i cant use the arrow key afterwards, only hit enter again to open the same website.

Here is my code (the comments are not that descriptive)

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import webbrowser

selectedButton=0

#functions needed

#function to toggle Fullscreen
def toogleFullScreen(event):
    global w, height1, width1
    w.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
    w.geometry("1920x650")

#function to open media
def openNetflix():
    global selectedButton
    webbrowser.open("https://www.netflix.com/")
    selectedButton = 0

def openArd():
    global selectedButton
    webbrowser.open("https://www.ardmediathek.de/")
    selectedButton = 1

def openZDF():
    global selectedButton
    webbrowser.open("https://www.zdf.de/")
    selectedButton = 2

def openYt():
    global selectedButton
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/")
    selectedButton = 3



def rightMove(event):
    global selectedButton
    selectedButton = selectedButton + 1
    if selectedButton > 3:
        selectedButton = 2

def leftMove(event):
    global selectedButton
    selectedButton = selectedButton - 1
    if selectedButton < 0:
        selectedButton = 0

def executeMove(event):
    global selectedButton
    if selectedButton == 0:
        openNetflix()
    elif selectedButton == 1:
        openArd()
    elif selectedButton == 2:
        openZDF()
    elif selectedButton == 3:
        openYt()

#make our tkinter window
w = Tk()
#make it Fullscreen
w.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
#window title
w.title("Mediathen Flanierer")

#binds
#assigns ESC to exit fullscreen
w.bind("<Escape>",  toogleFullScreen)
#right arrow selects different button
w.bind("<Right>", rightMove)
#left arrow selects different button
w.bind("<Left>", leftMove)
#on enter executes command
w.bind("<Return>", executeMove)

#make the window background red
w.config(bg='red')




#variables and pictures
#font size for Text
font1 = ("ARIAL", "25")
#width and height for Buttons
height1 = 1200
width1 = 473
#background color for buttons
bgColour = "lightblue"


#pictures
#variable to define the picture size
size= (450, 300)
#netflix logo
netflixPNG = Image.open("netflix.png")
netflixPNG= netflixPNG.resize(size, resample=0, box=None)
netflixPNG = ImageTk.PhotoImage(netflixPNG)
#ard logo
ardPNG = Image.open("ard.png")
ardPNG = ardPNG.resize(size, resample=0, box=None)
ardPNG = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ardPNG)
#zdf logo
zdfPNG = Image.open("zdf.png")
zdfPNG = zdfPNG.resize(size, resample=0, box=None)
zdfPNG = ImageTk.PhotoImage(zdfPNG)
#youtube logo
ytPNG = Image.open("youtube.png")
ytPNG = ytPNG.resize(size, resample=0, box=None)
ytPNG = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ytPNG)

#make our widgets with Tkinter
#netflix Button
ntflxBtn = Button(w, text="Netflix", cursor="arrow", command=openNetflix, image=netflixPNG, compound=TOP, height=height1, width=width1, background = bgColour, foreground="red", font=(font1)).grid(column=0, row = 0)

#ard Button
ardBtn = Button(w, text="ARD", image=ardPNG, cursor="arrow", command=openArd, compound=TOP, height=height1, width=width1, background=bgColour, foreground="red", font=(font1)).grid(column=1, row= 0)

#zdf Button
zdfBtn = Button(w, text="ZDF", image=zdfPNG, cursor="arrow", command=openZDF, compound=TOP,  height=height1, width=width1, background=bgColour,  foreground="red", font=(font1)).grid(column=2, row=0)

youtubeBtn = Button(w, text="Youtube", image=ytPNG, cursor="arrow", command=openYt, compound=TOP,  height=height1, width=width1, background=bgColour,  foreground="red", font=(font1)).grid(column=3, row=0)


w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try changing `w.bind(...)` to `w.bind_all(...)`

Comment: Works now, thank you